# suppose i have max(pid)=1001 if i want to display values of 1002 which is through +1 into max value so how can i do

Tags: sql

suppose i have `max(pid)=1001` if i want to display values of 1002 which is through +1 into max value so how can i do

This is my entire code i want to select max(pid) and want to display that into textbox

```
public PatientRegistration()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string connectionstring = "DATABASE=hmanagmentsystem;UID=root;PASSWORD=;SERVER=localhost";
        con = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring);
        con.Open();
    }

  private void PatientRegistration_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("select max(pid) from patientreg",con);
        int cmd=Int32.Parse(command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        con.Close();

    }
```

Comment: I am not sure what the question is here?
What do you want as output?

Comment: If `select max(pid) + 1 from patientreg` doesn't cut it, please elaborate on your question.

Comment: if command=100 tha is max(pid) and i want to display 1001 in textbox how can i do this

Comment: i want to display 1001 that value is not in database but we have max value which is 100 so how we can do 100+1=101 and than display 101 into textbox. every next time when we come so first our max value will be selected that +1 and than will be display

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("select max(pid) + 1 from patientreg", 
    con);
```

More fully:

```
string connectionString;
public PatientRegistration()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    connectionString = "DATABASE=hmanagmentsystem;UID=root;PASSWORD=;SERVER=localhost";
}

private void PatientRegistration_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open;

        using (SqlCommand = new SqlCommand("select max(pid) + 1 from patientreg",conn))
        {
            // this assumes an asp:TextBox called IDTextBox
            IDTextBox.Text = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```